# Input Patron Validacion Angular Texto con espacios Sin Caracteres Especiales, Numeros

Tags: html, angular, validación, input

Estoy Buscando un **Patron** para angular o en html *Que permita letras y espacios, pero no caracteres especiales, ni numeros* Como tal en un **Input:Type Text** con limitacion de longitud, Estube probando con:

**LetrasNombre: any = /^[A-Za-z\s]+[:print:]{1,71}/;**

```
 nombre[''[Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(70),Validators.minLength(2),Validators.pattern(this.LetrasNombre)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu regex esta mal. `+[:print:]{1,71}/` no es valido.

Segun [regex101](https://regex101.com).

> [:print:] A posix character class may only appear inside a character class
>
> {1,71} The preceding token is not quantifiable

Aun así, para lograr lo que quieres necesitas comprobar tambien `ñ` y `áéíóú`

Para eso existe `\u00f1` y  `\u00d1` que corresponden equivalentemente a `ñ` y  `Ñ`, pero con el modificador `i` se puede dejar solo `\u00f1`

Para el caso de `áéíóú` equivaldría a `\u00E0-\u00FC`.Por lo tanto el regex para `Validators.pattern` que necesitas es:

```
/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1\u00d1]*$/i
```

La longitud se puede definir en otra validación con `Validators.maxLength` para la cantidad máxima de caracteres y `Validators.required` para revisar que haya algo escrito en el campo.

> Aquí hay un choque. Si defines `Validator.minLength(1)` no se
> disparara la validación.

Las validaciones de tu campo quedarían así:

```
soloTexto: new FormControl('Por defecto', [
  Validators.pattern(/^[a-z\s\u00E0-\u00FC\u00f1]*$/i),
  Validators.maxLength(71),
  Validators.required
])
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/validaciones-patterns-regex-solo-letras?file=src/app/app.component.ts) en [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com).